# changing value of unordered list when selecting li item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question is, how do i change value of original element in UL list, after selecting/picking one li item under.

Example: I want to pick City3 and when i do, instead of "Pick City" it should be the value of "city3".

This is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHeyq/2/).
This is HTML:

```
<div class="menu1">
<li class="naslov"><b>Pick City</b></li>
<div class="submenu1">
    <ul id="sel">
        <li value="1"><a href="#"><b>City1</b></a></li>
        <li value="2"><a href="#"><b>City2</b></a></li>
        <li value="3"><a href="#"><b>City3</b></a></li>
        <li value="4"><a href="#"><b>City4</b></a></li>
        <li value="5"><a href="#"><b>City5</b></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also is it possible not to change any of the css/html(With that i mean, i dont want to add select,option elements), and make it work just over some JQuery/JS functions?

Thanks,
Milos

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#sel a').click(function(){
    $('li.naslov b').html(this.innerHTML);

    return false;
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bHeyq/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way to do this.  In this case, the li could be dynamic, based on an AJAX feed or some other JavaScript.

```
    $('#sel').on('click','li',function() {
       $('li.naslov b').text($(this).text());
    });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zX5U/1/)

Comment: 1. The demo doesn't work. 2. use `html` 3. don't add selectors to id selector. 4. don't use delegate event for no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your JS...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu1').hover(function(){
        $('.submenu1').stop(true).slideToggle('slow');
    });
    var orig = $(".naslov").html();
    $("#sel li").hover(function(){
        $(".naslov").html($(this).text());
    }, function(){
        $(".naslov").html(orig);
    });
});
```